# Disadvantage of FileChannel -> BufferedReader -> Reader

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filechannel

`FileChannel` will faster than `BufferedReader`, `BufferedReader` will more faster than `Reader` because `FileChannel` and `BufferedReader` has cut off some itermediate steps to receive data.

My question is : the advantage is obvious, but I don't see any source on web say about its disadvantage. (of `FileChannel` to `BufferedReader`, `BufferedReader` to `Reader`). What a problem when we cut off intermediate steps between.

So, who can teach me,please.

@:And, the same question for Output, too. Please tell me what disadvantage of those.

thanks :)

Comment: It may be obvious to you, but it isn't true. `BufferedReader` is much faster than `FileChannel`, because of the large internal buffer. And as `BufferedReader` *is* a `Reader`, it is meaningless to describe one as faster than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential disadvantage when using a `BufferedWriter` (or any of the other buffered output streams) is the fact that your program holds some data in the buffer/in memory before it is written to the output device. If you cannot afford to lose *any* data in case of a program crash then you may want consider not to use a `BufferedWriter`/`BufferedOutputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

I think because when you overcome intermediate steps, data stream will be more easy to meet error. And when errors happen, so difficult to trace bug.