# When NOT to use BufferedReader in reading text

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Is there really a reason when you would NOT use BufferedReader at all when reading text? I was trying to look for disadvantages but I can't seem to find any.

The reason I am asking is I would want to guarantee using BufferedReader right away whenever we encounter reading text files in our projects.

Comment: Take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246784/disadvantage-of-filechannel-bufferedreader-reader)

Comment: It's BufferedWriter. And IMO you won't really be losing data in case of a program crash cos it's still in a buffer, you still actually have the actual source.

Comment: No, there isn't a reason.

Comment: There are some tricks to keep in mind when processing text files, but those tricks have nothing to do with BufferedReader, or Scanner.  They have to do with the nature of text files that have line breaks in the middle of sentences and paragraphs.